# Why Composer uninstall things right after the installation?

Tags: composer-php

Composer keeps removing the files just after it installs them!
I used `composer create-project otra/skeleton --remove-vcs otra-user -vvv` to debug and it shows things like :

> - Installing otra/otra (1.0.0-alpha.2.4.0): Extracting archive
> Executing async command (CWD): unzip -qq -o '/var/www/html/perso/otra-user/vendor/composer/tmp-ad5334fdc8c968f8ad3d54814c2b67c1' -d '/var/www/html/perso/otra-user/vendor/composer/cc30fdc4'
> Executing command (CWD): rm -rf '/var/www/html/perso/otra-user/vendor/otra/otra'
> Executing command (CWD): rm -rf '/var/www/html/perso/otra-user/vendor/composer/cc30fdc4'

And as usual since a few months, it finished with the infinite loop that shows :

> 2 packages you are using are looking for funding.
> Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Nothing to modify in lock file
> Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
> Nothing to install, update or remove

Composer works like a charm before, I do not know what they have changed so I have all those issues now.

I have updated my Composer version and I did a `composer diagnose` but it shows nothing wrong.
I am using Composer 2.0.12 and PHP 8.0.3.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? "Keeps removing the files" sounds pretty strange

Comment: You seem to have an infinite loop in you scripts section. Your post-update script execute `composer update`, which triggers the `post-update` hook, etc.

Comment: @yivi I do not remember exactly why I put those `post-update-cmd` and `post-install-cmd` entries. I will remove them and try again. @Nico Haase I do not have any idea how can I debug the problem so I have not tried anything but I am really open to suggestions. Maybe fixing the loop will solve that too.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @yivi that pointed me to an another problem in `composer.json` where I indeed did a loop...
I solved my problem replacing `@otra-update` by `@otra-init` in `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` which was what I really wanted to do.

Thanks for your time @Nico Haase and @yivi :)